# Maven release another user credentials

Tags: java, maven

I want to perform

```
 mvn -B release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

But as a concrete user. How do I provide credentials for him? I was already trying with specyfing username/password in `.m2/settings.xml` like that:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>pass</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Here is a part of my pom.xml:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://myrepository.com/scm/svn/myapp/trunk/</developerConnection>
</scm>
<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <build>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>https://myrepository.com/scm/svn/myapp/tags</tagBase>
                    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mention the release plugin I assume you mean credentials for subversion, in which case settings.xml is the wrong place for them. The [plugin usage guide](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html) tells you how to pass credentials in:

```
mvn -Dusername=your_scm_username release:prepare
```

You can also use `-Dpassword` to add the password, or it will ask you for one.

Comment: Yes i was meaning SVN credentials. Is there any way to keep them separated from command?

Comment: I have to add that I am running this job with Jenkins

Comment: I have confgiured them with EnvInject Plugin, but they are visible in Console Output everytime the job is applied

Comment: Your question specifically mentions command line. However, Jenkins has a plugin to support maven release. If you perform your releases through there it allows you to provide credentials through the Jenkins UI.

Comment: Do you mean "M2 Release plugin"? I am not able to select there SVN credentials saved in Jenkins (like for svn pulling). I have only `Specify SCM login/password` option which force me to provide credentials by hand everytime I release version